# HTML character codes in jQuery 'if' conditions

Tags: jquery

If we have the HTML element `<p>&#339;</p>` (for example) and run the function

```
function test() {
    var inhtml = $("p").html();
    if (inhtml == "&#339;") { alert("Yes"); }
}
```

the alert is not displayed.

What do you need in the condition for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because calling `.html()` returns the parsed content, not the character code

Try

```
var inhtml = $("p").html();
if (inhtml == $($.parseHTML('&#339;')).text()) {
    alert("Yes");
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7QUf3)

or

```
var inhtml = $("p").html();
if (inhtml == 'œ') {
    alert("Yes");
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Vx8BT/)

Comment: Thank you! I'll use the first version since there are some characters you can't write in text editors.